# Python __setitem__ class variables

Tags: python, variables, object

I am trying to create a class with some variables.

```
def __setitem__(self, item, value):
    switch = {
        "hour" : self.hour,
        "minute" : self.minute,
        "second" : self.second,
        "day" : self.day,
        "dennidoby" : self.dennidoby,
        "season" : self.season,
        "month" : self.month,
        "year" : self.year,
        "dayr" : self.dayr,
        "dennitepl" : self.dennitepl,
        "pocasitepl" : self.pocasitepl,
        "wheather" : self.wheather,
        "temperature" : self.temperature,
        "obdobi" : self.obdobi,
        "den" : self.den,
        "mesic" : self.mesic
        }
    switch[item] = value
```

I call with code:

```
cas["wheather"] = "storm"
```

But:

```
switch[item] = value
```

Doesnt work for set variable in object.

Comment: What do you want to happen when you run this code? Without knowing that, it's pretty hard for anyone to tell you how to get what you want.

Answer (score 3):

Well, no. `switch` is a local variable: it will be deleted once the `__setitem__` method exits, and will be recreated with your hard-coded values the next time you call the method.

You should move the initial population of the variable to `__init__`, and refer to it as `self.switch` both there and in `__setitem__`.

Answer (score 2):

Each time you call `__setitem__`, you are creating a new dictionary called `switch`. You then update that dictionary with `switch[item] = value`. `switch` doesn't appear to be associated with the instance `self` at all. If you want instances of your class to have those key/value pairs, and you also want to update with `__setitem__`, I would do something like this:

```
class Cas(object):

    def __init__(self):
    self._switch = { ... #what you had...}

    def __setitem__(self, item, value):
        self._switch[item] = value

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return self._switch[item]
```

However, from what you shared, it might just make sense to use a `dict` or subclass `dict`

Answer (score 2):

You could change the value of an attribute dynamically using **setattr**(item, value). So your code will look like:

> ```
> def __setitem__(self, item, value):
>     self.__setattr__(item, value)
> ```
>
> That should do the task.